# Should an access token really be cryptographically signed?

Tags: web-applications, security, authentication

In a web app I'm writing, a singed-in user is recognized by their cookie containing a session identifier. That session id has sixty-four bits of entropy, so I believe brute-force attacks are impossible in practice. However, not signing it to prevent tampering still feels less secure than it ought to be.

I'd also like to keep the session id not signed not to increase the attack surface through the cryptography code I'm using, since I'm not a cryptography expert, and crypto is hard, so I always could get those details wrong.

But maybe I'm missing something? Is there an industry practice on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signed cookies/tokens are particularly useful when either

- the token is issued by one party but must be verified by a third party; or
- the contents of the token are guessable, so that tampered/forged tokens must be detected.

Since you only have a client–server scenario without any third parties, the first case doesn't apply. And the second case doesn't apply if you have truly random IDs with sufficient entropy, which you can compare with a list of active tokens in the backend.

You're only providing 64 bits of entropy, which may or may not be enough. The [Birthday attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) provides a relationship between number of bits, number of tokens, and chance of collision.

More entropy is comparatively cheap to get, so I'd instead suggest a UUIDv4 (122 bits of entropy) generated from a cryptographically secure entropy source, or a similar 128-bit random number. 128 bits is in line with the weakest cryptography in widespread use.

You're right to be concerned that inappropriate use of crypto could use problems, in particular when attempting to create cryptographically secure signatures from primitives. But this is not a problem in practice:

- you don't have to use any crypto if you use a cryptographically secure RNG instead, with entropy on the order of the size of the key you'd otherwise use
- you don't have to build cryptographic tools from scratch since there are widely available libraries for common tasks, such as for creating signed JSON Web Tokens (JWT).

Comment: also expiry dates